# Viscosity solution in for a non smooth value function

Tags: hamilton-jacobi-equation, viscosity-solutions

I am trying to find a solution for a free boundary problem, where the value function won't be smooth as it is in a multi period framework with fixed costs at each period. Resulting jumps in the boundary, and non smoothness of the value function.
I am trying to understand if I can apply a numerical solution with a finite difference method to approximate the derivatives. Is the solution would be a viscosity solution? Will it be unique?

Thanks

Comment: Your question is somewhat vague. It would be helpful if you could write down a simple version of your problem.

Comment: Thanks @Jeff. I will try to write a simple version: Say I have a free boundary problem with a Value function, V(x,t), where x is a an Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process. Our goal is to minimize V. However instead of the simple boundary condition where the boundary is set to the intersect between the value from continuation of V(x,t), and some payout function (say, g(x)=x) -  In this problem there are multiple boundaries with fixed cost in addition to the payout: V_n(x_t,t)=min{V_n(x_t+dt,t+dt), g(x_t)+Const+V_n-1(x_t+dt,t+dt} on a finite horizon where all n boundaries need to be crossed.